# SharePoint Client People Picker change event

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, people-picker, clientpeoplepicker

I am using the SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker control in my custom SharePoint page and would like to fire a change event when a user is selected from the list of users. I can see that there are multiple div's, hidden form field, span's etc when the ClientPeoplePicker is rendered. I tried multiple things like:

```
$('input[id$="TopSpan_HiddenInput"]').on('change', function(){
    alert('People Picker Value Changed');
});

$('span.sp-peoplepicker-resolveList').on('change',function(){
    alert('People Picker Value Changed');
});
```

But none works. Here's my code for ClientPeoplePicker

```
<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker Required="false" ID="cppProjectManager" runat="server" Width="100%" Title="ProjectManager" PrincipalAccountType="User" Rows="1" AllowMultipleEntities="false"  />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple events which you can handle for a Client People Picker Control. You can find detailed descriptions of those events [this](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2014/11/sharepoint-2013-client-side-people.html) blog.

To get the onChange of people picker, use following JavaScript snippet.

> Event will get two parameters – first one is the people picker id and second parameter is an array of selected users.
>
> This event will be fired if anything changes, like if user type text, user select a user from auto-fill list or user removes selected user. You can easily hook into the event as shown below:

**Updated Code**

```
SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_cppProjectManager_TopSpan.OnValueChangedClientScript=function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
    console.log('inside OnValueChangedClientScript');
};
```

**Note :** Check the client ID of people picker control by inspecting the HTML. Most probably it will be `ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_cppProjectManager_TopSpan`.

Comment: Not sure the issue, but when I tried the above, it gives me an error of "cannot read property SPClientPeoplePickerDict of undefined"

Comment: @Ashish: I have updated the code. please check now. Earlier I was using pure client side people picker as mentioned in this article. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-client-side-people-picker-control-in-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-in

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I just had to remove the "this" keyword.

Comment: To get the first people picker   `SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[Object.keys(SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict)[0]].OnValueChangedClientScript=function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {   
   console.log('inside OnValueChangedClientScript');  
  };`

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the picker id for SharePoint Client People Picker change event. I have got the same using `OnUserResolvedClientScript` as below. Here to get the picker div I have followed the approach of getting it via the people picker text box `id` and the `title name` which you can get the by inspecting the element. put the below code in  `$(document).ready` function and Njoy!

---

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function() {
        var pickerDiv = $("[id^='Employee_x0020_Name'][title='Employee Name']");
        var picker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv[0].id];
        picker.OnUserResolvedClientScript = function(peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
     //It will get the desired display name of the people from picker div, similarly any other property can be accessed via selectedUsersInfo
            var empname = selectedUsersInfo[0].DisplayText;
            console.log(empname);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit more detailed with Yayati's direction:
[image]