# track event for close of people picker and managed metadata value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to write code to track event when you click close/ cross button in people picker ?
How to track event when you clear all values in a managed metadata field ?

I have a requirement to display managed metadata field when people picker is empty .
Display people picker when managed metadata field is empty .

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor change event of managed metadata field by

```
RTE.CanvasEvents.registerListener(RTE.CanvasEvents.editableRegionChangedEvent, Function.createDelegate(null, onCustomTextChanged));
}
```

Reference below thread.
[jQuery - Detect value change on page and call routine](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187489/jquery-detect-value-change-on-page-and-call-routine)

For people picker change event, you may check below thread.

[SharePoint Client People Picker change event](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227519/sharepoint-client-people-picker-change-event)